# Append black frames to video when audio is longer in ffmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to utilize ffmpeg as a video editor and this is mostly due to that the regular video editor dropped more frames than I was comfortable with.

```
ffmpeg -i "videoplayback1" -t 00:09:51 -i "audioplayback1" -t 00:09:54.38 -vcodec libx264 -crf 20 -acodec copy "playback1.mp4"
```

As you can see, I'm trimming the video shorter than the audio, but what I want is something that is the opposite of the `-shortest` command switch, to have the file continue for the duration of the audio `-t`, and adding physical black frames for the remainder of that time.

As it is now, the video is still clipped as if I was using the `-shortest` switch. I tried some `-vf` and `filter_complex` but either I get errors, or that the audio is still chopped, the video frozen, but the duration is that of the longest `-t`.

How would I go about adding black frames for as long as the audio is playing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command is malformed in that it's not trimming the video shorter than the audio. Option placement matters. Input options for an input go before that input, so

```
ffmpeg -t 00:09:51 -i "videoplayback1" -t 00:09:54.38 -i "audioplayback1" -vcodec libx264 ...
```

For your editing requirement, I would drop the video trim and use the drawbox filter to blacken the frame after the desired video trim point.

```
ffmpeg -i "videoplayback1" -t 00:09:54.38 -i "audioplayback1" -vf drawbox=t=fill:enable='gt(t,591)' -shortest -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -c:a copy "playback1.mp4"
```

`drawbox`is set to draw over the whole frame with the default color of black after 591 seconds of video. `-shortest` terminates the output.

Comment: `Missing ')' or too many args in 'gt(t'` `Error when evaluating the expression 'gt(t' for enable` `Error initializing filter 'drawbox' with args 't=fill:enable=gt(t'` `Error opening filters!`

Comment: Sounds like you need to escape the comma. Make it `'gt(t\,591)'`

Comment: `Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'fill'`

Comment: You're using an older version of ffmpeg. Change fill to max.

Comment: Huh. And here I thought I was using the latest rep. Also, now using your command with max and escaped comma, the whole video stopped at the shortest `-t`. Removing `-shortest` added about 20 seconds to the end of the audio.

Comment: Well, I meant what the shortest `-t` would've been. But, actually, I double checked my command line because I thought I didn't include the first `-t` but apparently I had. Thanks. It works as it should.